# Possible outcomes of getting specific pixels of an area?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we have an area called $G$ containing $g$ pixels. Inside of this area is a subarea called $F$ containing $f$ pixels. Obviously we have $F\subset G$

Now we will choose randomly 4 pixels from this area with the Random variable $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$ with uniform distribution.

The question is how many possible outcomes do we have if one of the $X_i$ will point to the set $\{1,\ldots,f\}$ and the other three $X_i$ will point to the set $\{f+1,\ldots,g\}$

My idea was that one of the $X_i$ will get to the subarea $F$ with $\frac{F}{G}$ and the remaining three $X_i$ to the area without G with $\frac {G-F} {G}$

$$\frac{F}{G}\cdot \frac {G-F} {G}\cdot\frac {G-F} {G}\cdot\frac {G-F} {G}=a$$

We can shuffle through the four elements therefore it would be $4\cdot a$
Does this way work out?[image]

Comment: If you can choose a specific pixel not only once then your approach looks fine to me.